# Accessing Kafka Stream State Store with Spring

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Referencing 4.2.6 of this doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka-streams

How do you get access to state stores using kafka stream spring support?

Without spring you could do?

```
StreamsBuilder builder = ...;
// Start an instance of the topology
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);

...

// Get the key-value store CountsKeyValueStore
ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, Long> keyValueStore =
    streams.store("CountsKeyValueStore", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
```

But I am not sure how to gain acess to KafkaStreams object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Autowire the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` (or otherwise get a reference to it from the application context) and call `getKafkaStreams()`.

Comment: Thank you! Autowired and then can access via streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()